# Why do we need event indexed params?

Tags: contract-design, contract-development

As stated in the [docs](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Solidity-Features#events):

> [...] Up to three parameters can receive the attribute indexed which will
>   cause the respective arguments to be treated as log topics instead of
>   data. The hash of the signature of the event is always one of the
>   topics. All non-indexed arguments will be stored in the data part of
>   the log.

What are the possible use cases of having event arguments as log topics?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Storing the event arguments as log topics will allow you to use these indexed arguments in your event filters. From [Contracts - Events](http://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/contracts.html#events):

> Up to three parameters can receive the attribute indexed which will cause the respective arguments to be searched for: It is possible to filter for specific values of indexed arguments in the user interface.

And from [JavaScript-API - Contract Events](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-events):

> ```
> var event = myContractInstance.MyEvent({valueA: 23} [, additionalFilterObject])
>
> // watch for changes
> event.watch(function(error, result){
>   if (!error)
>     console.log(result);
> });
>
> // Or pass a callback to start watching immediately
> var event = myContractInstance.MyEvent([{valueA: 23}] [, additionalFilterObject] , function(error, result){
>   if (!error)
>     console.log(result);
> });
> ```
>
> You can use events like filters and they have the same methods, but you pass different objects to create the event filter.
>   Parameters
>
> 1. Object - Indexed return values you want to filter the logs by, e.g. {'valueA': 1, 'valueB': [myFirstAddress, mySecondAddress]}. By default all filter values are set to null. It means, that they will match any event of given type sent from this contract.
> 2. Object - Additional filter options, see filters parameter 1 for more. By default filterObject has field 'address' set to address of the contract. Also first topic is the signature of event.
> 3. Function - (optional) If you pass a callback as the last parameter it will immediately start watching and you don't need to call myEvent.watch(function(){}). See this note for details.

Answer (score 5):

to sum up what BokkyPooBah just said, it's essentially to give you the capability to work with your logs in a database type context and filter through your logs to find exactly what you need and program around it thusly.